# PureScript "Could not match type" error for a Record

Tags: html5-canvas, purescript

I'm following one of the [exercises](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-exercises-22) in the PureScript book where I have to define a function `renderPath` that takes an array of `Point`s (x and y) and draws a path using them (using `purescript-canvas`), where a `Point` is defined as

```
type Point = { x :: Number, y :: Number }
```

I've decided to split the function into two steps. The first step is to `moveTo` the first point in the array and then use `lineTo` over the remaining points.

Here is the function I've written so far which only has the first step. But I get this one error that I just can't figure out.

Here's the function

```
import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Data.Array.Partial (head, tail)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Graphics.Canvas (CANVAS, Context2D, arc, closePath, fillPath, getCanvasElementById, getContext2D, lineTo, moveTo, rect, setStrokeStyle, strokePath)
import Partial.Unsafe (unsafePartial)

renderPath :: forall eff
. Context2D
-> Array Point
-> Eff (canvas :: CANVAS | eff) Unit

renderPath ctx points = fillPath ctx $ do
  p0 <- unsafePartial head points
  moveTo ctx p0.x p0.y
```

And I get this one error at `p0` in the last line of the function (`moveTo ctx p0.x p0.y`)

The error is:

```
  Could not match type

    { x :: Number
    | t0         
    }            

  with type

    ( x :: Number
    , y :: Number
    )            


while checking that type ( x :: Number
                         , y :: Number
                         )            
  is at least as general as type { x :: Number
                                 | t0         
                                 }            
while checking that expression p0
  has type { x :: Number
           | t0         
           }            
while checking type of property accessor p0.x
in value declaration renderPath

where t0 is an unknown type
```

I'm assuming that `p0` should be of the type `{ x :: Number, y :: Number }`

This error shows one as `{ x :: Number | t0 }` and the other as `( x :: Number, y :: Number)`. I don't understand this at all. Why is one using `{}` and the other `()`. What's the difference between them? Where am I going wrong?

I'd also request an explanation along with any correction as I'm new to PureScript and functional programming as a whole so I'm having trouble trying to understand a lot of concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you get that particular error message, but one issue with your code is this line:

```
p0 <- unsafePartial head points
```

this is supposed to be

```
let p0 = unsafePartial (head points)
```

`<-` in a `do` block means something like "get the value out of the context of `Eff`". But since `unsafePartial (head points)` is not an `Eff`, the types don't match and you get an error message.

this code compiles:

http://try.purescript.org/?backend=flare&gist=6baa84215d33bf6f11c808e24b95c72f